# Object required vba

Tags: vba

I have this code below where Set x does not work. Which is weird as the Set f does. I have no idea why, I am in the middle of my code and this simply does not work. It is the same as Set f in my point of view. Any ideas why?

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim WsOuput As Worksheet
Dim WsScenarios As Worksheet
Dim ScenarioIDrow As Long
Dim ScenarioIDColumn As Long
Dim ScenarioIDinScenarios As Long
Dim ScenarioIDinScenariosC As Long
Dim p As String
Dim q As String
Dim x As Range
Dim z As String
Dim r As String
Dim RgnScenarioOutput As Range
Dim RgnScenarioScenario As Range
Dim Findsomething As Range
Dim FindAgain As Range
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim f As Range
Dim fAgainAddress As Range

Set WsOutput = Worksheets("Output")
Set WsScenarios = Worksheets("Scenarios.New")
lLastRow = WsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
r = WsOutput.Cells(lLastRow, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Range("B22").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Scenarios.New").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select

    Set f = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets("Output").Range("B22").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    f.Select
    q = f.Address
    Set x = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    x.Select
    z = x.Address

    Range("F21:M21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("AFI35").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate` returning an object?

Comment: Is `FindNext.Activate` the correct syntax?

Comment: You should probably rewrite all this without resorting to `.Select` and `.Activate`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx

Comment: thank you guys! you were right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Andrew Cheong (and Chrismas007) commented, your problem is with your `Activate` Method.

A `Range.Activate` command does not return an object (it just activates something), so it is not possible to `Set` something to a `Range.Activate`.

You probably want to change:

```
Set x = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
```

to:

```
Set x = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)
If Not x Is Nothing Then x.Activate
```

Comment: No love for my syntax comment? :-P

Comment: @Chrismas007 - In my defence, I started typing the answer before you posted your comment - I will amend my answer to give you credit as well ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I'm happy with the edit you made, but strictly speaking it isn't required to `maintain original functionality` - the original functionality would be achieved anyway by the `x.Select` statement that follows the `Set` statement.

Comment: Ah, good point - I was only looking at the code in the answer! =)  ...mind you, that `.Select` is going to blow up if `x` is nothing, so it's still good to have that null-check in there, just to remind OP that there's a possible runtime error 91 there.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - which is why I was happy for the edit to be left.  I was actually thinking of adding something similar myself, but then decided I would need to rewrite **all** the code to handle those sort of problems, and I was feeling too tired to go to that much trouble.

Comment: you guys are great. I am still learning and I learn from all of you. great!

Answer (score 2):

You Can use this

```
Dim x As Range
Dim f As Range
Set f = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets("Output").Range("B22").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    f.Select
    q = f.Address
    Set x = Range("A:A").FindNext(f)
    x.Select
```

Comment: @LeandroMoreira note that `x.Select` will raise a runtime error 91 if `FindNext` doesn't find anything. The other answer addresses that problem.

Comment: Make sure You handle it properly when x returns null/Nothing. As http://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug has Mentioned you may run into Error 91.

Comment: Hi. It does not comes any error. My idea here is to set the address of the first one and the address of the second one. in this case they are the same. In case the addresses are different I want to copy the row